# List articleName in the json

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I have a json file as shown below.How to display articleName as a list using angularjs and ionic.I think the json is nested one as shown below.

```
{"articles":[{"articleId":"2665","articleName":"<\/head>Parental leave<\/body><\/html>"}]}


<ion-list>
    <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let film of data">
      {{ film.articles.articleName }}
    </ion-item
  </ion-list>
```

i followed this tutorial

https://ionicacademy.com/fix-cors-issues-native-http/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngFor` is a Structural Directive that lets you loop over an array.

`articles` is an array. You should be looping over that instead of the `film` which I don't think is anything in your particular context.

Considering your `data` is:

```
data = {"articles":[{"articleId":"2665","articleName":"<\/head>Parental leave<\/body><\/html>"}]}
```

In your template:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let article of data.articles">
    {{ article.articleName }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I am using this function to retrieve data async getDataStandard() { let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create(); await loading.present(); this.http.get('labourguide.co.za/LabourguideApi/…( finalize(() => loading.dismiss()) ) .subscribe(data => { this.data = data['results']; }, err => { console.log('JS Call error: ', err); }); } Is it correct to use this.data = data['results'];

Comment: @SiddAjmera.I am getting the following error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (main.page.ts:25)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:192)
    at

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this
*ngFor loop is iterate over the array of object. so here you can see that we are iterating a loop over `data.articles` if you want to iterate the loop over the object then you can use the `keyvalue` pipe

**TS**

```
let data = {"articles":[{"articleId":"2665","articleName":"<\/head>Parental leave<\/body><\/html>"}]}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- with out keyvalue pipe so we are iterating a loop over the array of object -->
<ion-list>
    <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let film of data.articles; let i = index;">
      {{ film.articleName }}
    </ion-item
  </ion-list>

<!-- with keyvalue pipe so we are iterating a loop over object -->
<ion-list>
    <ion-item button detail lines="inset" *ngFor="let film of articles | keyvalue; let i = index;">
      {{ film | json}}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Comment: I am using this function to retrieve data 

 
  async getDataStandard() {
    let loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create();
    await loading.present();
 
    this.http.get('https://www.labourguide.co.za/LabourguideApi/index.php?q=mostRecentPublications').pipe(
      finalize(() => loading.dismiss())
    )
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data['results'];
    }, err => {
      console.log('JS Call error: ', err);
    });
  }

Is it correct to use  this.data = data['results'];

Comment: yes it is correct way to do. so you if you want to iterate over the object the you can use `keyvalue`. so your response is not giving you the array of object it is giving you the object which contain the array of object so if you want to use directly the response so you have to use `keyvalue` pipe. other wise `*ngFor="let film of data.articles;`

Comment: but my json starts as  {"articles": ..And in the tutorial the json starts with results .That is why i am confused

Comment: then use `keyvalue` pipe. what i'm telling you is that if you dont want to display the "articles" as a text in html then there is no point to using a `keyvalue` pipe you can directly use `data.articles` and iterate the loop.

Comment: can you please give me a sample code snippet for that

Comment: I am getting error as core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'articles' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (main.page.ts:26)
    at SafeSubscri